# How can i find the minimum interval that contains half of n numbers?

Tags: algorithm

If I have n numbers , how do I find the minimum interval [a,b] that contains half of those numbers ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well my only solution was to split the numbers into 2 intervals [a,n/2] and [n/2,b] but this is not the best .

Comment: it depends, are the numbers sorted? if so wouldn't the first be the smallest interval of n?

Comment: @Alex Giucăl I don't believe that this is real solution - a and b are unknown a priori

Comment: the numbers are not sorted , and my solution was not good ,that's why i am asking

Comment: If I understand the question, you shouldn't say the *minimum* interval but the *shortest* one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, your existing code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sort numbers
Set `left` index to 0, `right` to `n/2-1`, get difference `A[right]-A[left]`
Walk n/2 steps in for-loop, incrementing both indexes, calculating difference again, remember the smallest one and corresponding indexes.

Comment: You mean the smallest one, don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the numbers increasingly and compute all the differences `A[i+n/2] - A[i]`. The solution is given by the index that minimizes the difference.

---

**Explanation:**

There is no need to search among the intervals that contain less than n/2 numbers (because they do not satisfy the conditions) nor those that contain more elements (because if you find a suitable interval, it won't be minimal because you can remove the extreme elements).

When the elements are sorted, any sequence in the array is bounded by its first and last elements. So it suffices to sort the numbers and slide a window of n/2 elements.

---

Now it is more challenging to tell if this O(n log n) approach is optimal.

Answer (score -1):

How about the following?

- Sort the given series of numbers in ascending order.
- Start a loop with i from 1st to ([n/2])th number
- Calculate the difference d between i + ([n/2])th and ith number. Store the numbers i, i + [n/2] and d in an iteratable collection `arr`.
- End loop
- Find the minimum value of d from the array `arr`. The values of i and i + [n/2] corresponding to this d is your smallest range.

Comment: This solution was already given, and storing the deltas in an array is overkill.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the solution is not given in any answers. Rather than downvoting a good answer, try to make it better. It will benefit the community.

Comment: The solution was given twice. Do read the posts and accept the criticism. I precisely told you in what way you can improve.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, "storing the deltas in an array is overkill" is a mere suggestion for improvement. It doesn't make the answer wrong and hence worthy for a downvote.

Comment: don't be bad faith. You moaned for "try to make it better", which is precisely what I did. And don't be bad faith, the solution was shown twice before. My -2 for your bad faith and uncalled-for insistance.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, you need to read SD rules to understand "try to make it better" means. In fact, you had already downvoted the answer before my "moaning". Because of aggressive downvoters like you, many new users who want to contribute are feeling discouraged.

Comment: I had already suggested the improvement before your moaning. You reap what you saw.